# Netcat Android missing UDP support

Tags: android, udp, netcat, busybox

I would use Netcat with UDP protocoll on Android, but Busibox based nc not  supports UDP.

~$ nc -u -w1 -p10000 192.168.178.31 10000
nc: invalid option -- u
BusyBox v1.23.2-Stericson (2015-04-10 10:51:32 CDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [-iN] [-wN] [-l] [-p PORT] [-f FILE|IPADDR PORT] [-e PROG]

Open a pipe to IP:PORT or FILE

```
    -l      Listen mode, for inbound connects
            (use -ll with -e for persistent server)
    -p PORT Local port
    -w SEC  Connect timeout
    -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
    -f FILE Use file (ala /dev/ttyS0) instead of network
    -e PROG Run PROG after connect
```

I'm on Lollipop (Samsung Note3 N9005). 
Maybe Busybox, netcat android is the reason.

Best Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

not use busybox nc, use /system/xbin/nc insteaded;

```
root@htc_a31dtul:/ # nc
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
      [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-s source] [-T ToS]
      [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
```

Comment: Good advise! Thank you! Unfortunately Samsung lollipop doesn't have  /system/xbin/nc  in  stock ROM. I have checked 2 stock ROM....

Comment: You must be using a special ROM, this is not available in the stock Pixel ROM